# Sending information from servlets to jsp pages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

It is a requirement of my assignment that we send information from the java servlet to the jsp page.

My question is regarding calling a function. It has a sql query in it that finds multiple results the problem I'm having is that it is only returning the very last in the result set to the jsp page, NOT ALL THE RESULTS.

Here is the servlet:

```
private void sendBack(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    //Set data you want to send back to the request (will be forwarded to the page)
//Can set string, int, list, array etc.
String sql = "SELECT id, user_id" +
          " FROM lab" +
        " WHERE user_id=" + (Integer)session.getAttribute("id");

  try{
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
    System.out.println("got boobs");
    System.out.println(session.getAttribute("id"));

  Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (res.next()){
      do{
           list1.add(res.getString(1));
           list1.add(res.getString(2));
      }while(res.next());

      request.setAttribute("res", res);
      }
      for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
          System.out.println(list1.get(i));
      }
  }catch (SQLException e) {
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    } 


    //Decides what page to send the request data to
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("Student_manage.jsp");
    //Forward to the page and pass the request and response information
    view.forward(request, response); 
}
```

and here is the jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Mars University Lab System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<jsp:include page="headerStudent.jsp"/>


<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div id = "centrecontent">
<br>
<h3>Manage Timetable</h3>

  TESTING THE NO FORM REDIRECTION HERE:<br>

<% String data1 = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("data1")); %>
 <% String data2 = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("data2")); %>
<%=data1 %>
<%=data2 %>


</div>

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>


</body>

</html>
```

I believe I need some sort of do statement in the jsp page to step through each result.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is wrong

You iterate a row of the `rs` and store it in the request attributes `data1` and `data2`.
Then you get the next row and you **overwrite** the same attributes over and over again.

And therefore you are left with the last value of the `rs`.

I think it would be better to store your results in a `Collection`, and then store your `Collection` in your `request` object

**UPDATE1**

Consider this sample code

```
public class MyObject{
  private String data1;
  private String data2;
    public void setData1(String data1) {
        this.data1 = data1;
    }

    public String getData1() {
        return data1;
    }

    public void setData2(String data2) {
        this.data2 = data2;
    }

    public String getData2() {
        return data2;
    }
}
```

This is your Object.

Then Do the changes in your code above like this:

```
List <MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
if (res.next()){
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    do{
          obj.setData1(res.getString(1));
          obj.setData2(res.getString(2));
          list.add(obj);
    }while(res.next());

request.setAttribute("results", list);
}
```

This will add the `List` in a request attribute named `results`

Then you can retrieve the list using

```
List <MyObject> results = (List<MyObject>) request.getAttribute("results");
```

**UPDATE2**

PS: It is a good practice to remove the `do/while` loop because it is error prone and replace it with a `while` like this

```
    while(res.next()){
          obj.setData1("data1", res.getString(1));
          obj.setData2("data2", res.getString(2));
          list.add(obj);
    }
```

**UPDATE3**

Print it to jsp like this

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
  List <MyObject> results = (List<MyObject>) request.getAttribute("results");
  for(MyObject obj : results){
    out.write(obj.getData1() + " "+ obj.getData2() + "<br/>";
  }
%>
```

Comment: i updated my code so now it gets the entire array, how do i print it out in my jsp now?/

Comment: @user1393064.. while loop.. In your scriplet.. as you have to use it.. no other way..

Comment: you can use JSTL for iterating